# Use the first law of thermodynamics to derive the pressure as a function of T, U, V and N

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, pressure, ideal-gas

I am struggling with a thermodynamics question given
$$S(U,V,N)=C_VNK_\mathrm b\ln U/U_0+NK_\mathrm b\ln V/V_0$$ (where $U_0$ and $V_0$ are the reference energies and volumes) and the first law of thermodynamics which is $\mathrm dU=T\,\mathrm dS-p\,\mathrm dV+\mu\,\mathrm dN$. The question asks to use the two expressions above to derive the pressure $p$ as a function of $T$, $U$, $V$ and $N$.

Would anyone be able to give me a hint as to where to start with this question?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: Start by writing $dS=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V,N}dU+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U,N}dV+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_{U,V}dN$

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the entropy function is for a thermodynamic system of a pure fluid. So let me:

1. Define $ s \triangleq S/N $ to have the entropy per molecule.
2. Multiply both sides for Avogadro's number $N_A$ to have the molar entropy $N_As$ in the left-hand side and the $R$ constant in the right-hand side.
3. If you don't mind, I will abuse the notation a bit, and also call this new guy also $s$.
4. Eliminate the $C_V$ that appears in your equation, it seems to be a typo, and also it is not dimensionally correct.

The molar entropy then is
$$ s(u,v) = R\ln\left(\dfrac{u}{u_0}\right) + R\ln\left(\dfrac{v}{v_0}\right)\tag{1} $$
We can also put the molar internal energy in terms of the molar entropy and molar volume
$$ u(s,v) = u_0 \exp\bigg[\dfrac{s-R\ln(v/v_0)}{R}\bigg] \tag{2} $$
The first law for a closed system and a pure fluid yields
$$ du = -Pdv + Tds \tag{3} $$
For an isentropic process, we take the appropriate partial derivative for Eq. (2) and see what the 1st law tells us
\begin{align}
  -P &= \bigg(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial v}\bigg)_s \\
  -P &= u_0 \exp\bigg[\dfrac{s-R\ln(v/v_0)}{R}\bigg]\bigg(-\frac{1}{v}\bigg) \\
  -P &= u\bigg(-\frac{1}{v}\bigg) \rightarrow P = \dfrac{u}{v} \tag{4}
\end{align}
We could end here but we should continue. For an isochoric process, we take the appropriate partial derivative for Eq. (1), and see what the 1st law tells us
\begin{align}
  du &= Tds \\
  \dfrac{1}{T} &= \bigg(\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial u}\bigg)_v \\
  \dfrac{1}{T} &= R\left(\dfrac{1}{u}\right) \rightarrow u = RT \tag{5}
\end{align}
Combining Eqs. (4) and (5)
$$ \boxed{P = \dfrac{RT}{v} = \dfrac{nRT}{V} = \dfrac{Nk_BT}{V}} $$
This is, the entropy function they gave you is that of an ideal gas.